# Как сортировать результат запроса от нескольких mysql таблиц по id в другой таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, join

Есть большой массив товаров $result, полученных из разных таблиц mysql table1,table2,table3 и т.д.  При этом имеется также отдельная таблица ordered, в которой указан уникальный артикул artikul товара и его порядковый номер id. Как упорядочить вывод товаров из table1,table2,table3 по этому id, если он находится в другой таблице? Запросы осуществляются на php.

Comment: Собрать всё в один запрос.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT total.*
FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM table2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM table3
      ) AS total
LEFT JOIN ordered ON total.artikul = ordered.artikul 
ORDER BY ordered.id
```